# Headings with a hanging subhead

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment

I use this piece of code to add a subhead (usually a quick reference) in my notes:

```
\newcommand{\mysection}[2]{\section[#1]{#1\\*[.6ex]\normalsize\textit{#2}}}
```

I'd like to make the subtitle hanging from the section number, which for sections I have managed to do with

```
\newcommand{\mysection}[2]
  {\section[#1]{#1\\*[.6ex] \normalsize\textit{\hphantom{\Huge\thesection}#2}}}
  % I'm quite sure there is a cleaner way.
```

[image]

but this approach doesn't work with subsections for none of the sizes of the phantom number properly aligns the subhead.

Should I use a box instead of the `\hphantom`?

N.B. I use

```
 \documentclass[twoside,fleqn]{scrartcl}
 \setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
```

---

Edit

@karlkoeller Your code works. I've added a subtitle referring to the Wikipedia to your MWE, it spits out a text that is a tiny little bit out of alignment (I've cut out the numbers):

[image]

But I guess it is because of the italics.

Comment: Indeed, using the 'old' code (thus removing the hanging indent) leaves the same 'disalignment.'

Comment: This is because of the shape of the italic `W`... Change `\textit` to `\textup` to see that the spacing described in my answer is correct. If you really need to change it you can specify something like `\hspace*{-2pt}Wikipedia` for that particular case.

Comment: Yup I see... Sorry for the mistrust ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right amount of spacing for the section (in `scrartcl` class) is given by

```
\hphantom{\thesection\enskip}
```

typeset in upright `\Large` characters.

So your definition for `\mysection` is wrong, and should be instead:

```
\newcommand{\mysection}[2]
  {\section[#1]{#1\\*[.6ex]\Large\textup{\hphantom{\thesection\enskip}}\normalsize\textit{#2}}}
```

A similar `\mysubsection` command can be defined, remembering that for a subsection the amount of spacing is given by

```
\hphantom{\thesubsection\enskip}
```

typeset in upright `\large` characters:

```
\newcommand{\mysubsection}[2]
  {\subsection[#1]{#1\\*[.4ex]\large\textup{\hphantom{\thesubsection\enskip}}\small\textit{#2}}}
```

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside,fleqn]{scrartcl}
 \setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}

\newcommand{\mysection}[2]
  {\section[#1]{#1\\*[.6ex]\Large\textup{\hphantom{\thesection\enskip}}\normalsize\textit{#2}}}

\newcommand{\mysubsection}[2]
  {\subsection[#1]{#1\\*[.4ex]\large\textup{\hphantom{\thesubsection\enskip}}\small\textit{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\mysection{A section}{A section subtitle}

\mysubsection{A subsection}{A subsection subtitle}

\end{document}
```

gives the desired result

[image]

---

For references, see p.99 of the KOMA-Script manual

> The original
>   definitions for the KOMA-Script classes are:
>
> `\newcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{\thesection\autodot\enskip}`
>
> `\newcommand*{\subsectionmarkformat}{\thesubsection\autodot\enskip}`

In your case, `\autodot` produces no spacing since you are not using the option `numbers=enddot` or equivalent.

Comment: Your code sets a bit too much indentation in my document. Can't figure out why... Also, why did you use `.4ex` linespread? I mean, it makes sense but is it a personal choice or something related to the font size? Last (newbie tell-tale) question, how do you know the spacing of the headings is `\thesection\enspace`? I've looked for a document with these values but didn't find it. I'm going to provide a MWE in minutes, I can't right now.

Comment: @ArchStanton The definition in `scrartcl` refers to `\enskip` and not to `\enspace` (changed in the answer) but the meaning is a spacing of `.5em` anyway. I've used `.4ex` just for differentiating it from the `\mysection` command, but it's just a matter of taste.